# Meaning of “Alles steht Kopf”

Tags: meaning-in-context

This is the German title of the Pixar movie *Inside Out*.

Given that the movie is about the world seen by the emotions inside the main character, I would translate it like “Everything standing in the head”.

On the other hand, it seems that **auf dem Kopf stehen** means "standing on the head" (like when you are upside down) — [source](http://www.linguee.com/german-english/translation/auf+dem+Kopf+stehen.html).

So I am asking: What could be the literal translation of this German title?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Literally, it does mean *everything stands on the head*. Figuratively, it means either

> everything goes wild (with enthusiasm, for example)

Or

> everything is upside down, in turmoil, (even: all hell broke loose)

The latter would make most sense in this context.